# Convert "YYYYMMDD" format string to date in MDX?

Tags: sql-server-2012, mdx, date-format, date-conversion

I have some issue with applying date related functions on the "YYYYMMDD" format string in MDX. For example, if I have this query below:

```
with 
    member foo as WEEKDay("2013-03-21")
select
    foo on 0
from 
    [Some Cube]
```

It will correctly output "5" for foo in SSMS. But if I change the second line to:

```
   member foo as WEEKDay("20130321")
```

Unfortunately, it will throw "type mismatch" error.

So what I want to do is that converting the string to some recognizable date format and then applying the functions on it. Any ideas for the easiest way, e.g. using existing functions?

**Please note** that the string is actually inputted from members in any cube where the MDX is running on. So the string format could have been recognizable, e.g. "YYYY-MM-DD". So hard coded string converting algorithm may not be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Topic is too old, but maybe this may help someone. Technique is quite brute, but scalable.

```
with 
    member foo_false as WeekDay("20130321")
    member foo_true as WeekDay("2013-03-21")
    member foo_brute as 
    case when IsError(WeekDay("20130321"))=False then WeekDay("20130321") else
        case
        /* YYYYMMDD */
        when 
        IsError(WeekDay("20130321"))=True AND IsNumeric("20130321")=True
        and IsError(WeekDay(Left("20130321",4)+'-'+Right(Left("20130321",6),2)+'-'+Right("20130321",2)))=False
            then WeekDay(Left("20130321",4)+'-'+Right(Left("20130321",6),2)+'-'+Right("20130321",2))

        /* DDMMYYYY */
        when 
        IsError(WeekDay("20130321"))=True AND IsNumeric("20130321")=True
        and IsError(WeekDay(Right("20130321",4)+'-'+Right(Left("20130321",4),2)+'-'+Left("20130321",2)))=False
            then WeekDay(Right("20130321",4)+'-'+Right(Left("20130321",4),2)+'-'+Left("20130321",2))

        /* MMDDYYYY */
        when 
        IsError(WeekDay("20130321"))=True AND IsNumeric("20130321")=True
        and IsError(WeekDay(Right("20130321",4)+'-'+Left("20130321",2)+'-'+Right(Left("20130321",4),2)))=False
            then WeekDay(Right("20130321",4)+'-'+Left("20130321",2)+'-'+Right(Left("20130321",4),2))

        /* Unsupported Message */
        else "Unsupported Format" end
    end
select
    {foo_false,foo_true,foo_brute} on 0
from 
    [DATA Cube]
```

Adding supportable formats to the end before "Unsupported", use any input string instead of `"20130321"`.

But the easiest way is to use another layer (e.g. SQL function CONVERT) before inserting to MDX if possible, sure thing.

Answer (score 0):

The vba function `isDate` can be used to check if the passed date is well formatted. If not then format it first using `dateserial` and `mid` and use them.

```
with 
member foo as "20130321"

member bar as   
iif(vba!isdate(foo) = TRUE, 
    WEEKDay(foo), //--if the date is already well formatted, it can be used
    WEEKday(vba!dateserial(vba!mid(foo, 0, 4), vba!mid(foo, 5, 2), vba!right(foo, 2))))
select
    bar on 0
from 
    [some cube]
```

**EDIT**

The above code *can* be modified to accommodate other checks such as `MMDDYYYY` or `DDMMYYYY`, but the thing is it is impossible  in lot of cases for the engine to intuitively know if the passed value is in `YYYYMMDDDD` or `DDMMYYYY` or `MMDDYYYY`. Take for example the string `1111111`

This could easily be in any date format as it is a valid date howsoever you break it.

I would suggest that you have another member which can store the date format as well. That way looking at this member, string can be parsed.

e.g.

```
with 
member foo as 
//  "20130321" //YYYYMMDD
//  "03212013"//MMDDYYYY
"21032013"//DDMMYYYY

MEMBER dateformat as "ddmmyyyy"



member bar as   
iif(vba!isdate(foo) = TRUE, 
    WEEKDay(foo), 
    IIF(dateformat = "yyyymmdd", //YYYYMMDD
        WEEKday(vba!dateserial(vba!mid(foo, 0, 4), vba!mid(foo, 5, 2), vba!right(foo, 2))), 
        IIF(dateformat = "mmddyyyy", //MMDDYYYY
            WEEKday(vba!dateserial(right(foo, 4), vba!mid(foo, 0, 2), vba!mid(foo, 3, 2))),
            IIF(dateformat = "ddmmyyyy", //DDMMYYYY
                WEEKday(vba!dateserial(right(foo, 4), vba!mid(foo, 3, 2), vba!mid(foo, 0, 2))),
                null
               )
            )
        )
    )

select
    bar on 0
from 
    [aw cube]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `FooMember` being an int here, representing a `yyyyMMdd` date I could convert it to Date using the following code

```
   =Format(CDate(Left(CSTR(Fields!FooMember.Value),4)
   + "-" + Mid(CSTR(Fields!FooMember.Value), 5, 2)
   + "-" + Right(CSTR(Fields!FooMember.Value), 2)),
   "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

use it in a cube using the following code

```
 Format(CDate(Left([Measures].[FooMember],4)
 + "-" + Mid([Measures].[FooMember], 5, 2)
 + "-" + Right([Measures].[FooMember], 2)),"yyyy/MM/dd")
```